# Sql queries doesnt work when inside a php function

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

So the main problem is, when i make some query just after a post[] or whatever and its just in the main code of the php (not in a function) it works perfectly fine..
But, when i try and have that query inside a php function,it never works, and kinda hiding any other code on the rest of the page... I have a few divs after that php and sql query code, and they just dont show when i try to query through the function..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callPhpVoteAdd(name) {
        var result = <?php voteAdd(name); ?>;
        alert(result);
        return false;
    }
</script>
<?php
echo '</br>';
$allsql = "SELECT * FROM voting ORDER BY votes DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $allsql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $name = $row["name"];
        $votes = $row["votes"];
        echo '<form method="post">
        name: "' .$name. '" - votes: "' .$votes. '" <input type="submit" name="'.$name.'" value="'.$name.'" onclick="callPhpVoteAdd(this.name)"/><br>
        </form>';
    }
}
function voteAdd($name) {
    if($conn->query("UPDATE voting SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE name = '".$name."' ") === TRUE) {
        echo "<script>alert('fuck yeah');</script>";
    }
    echo "shit";
}
```

So the button pressed calls the js function, which calls the php function

Comment: Add your code and don't ignore rules next time.

Comment: @svgrafov Thank you, edited

Comment: Learn how to use parameters.  Munging query strings can lead to syntax errors and SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: PHP code is run server-side and once per page load. Your code with execute that query *at load time* not when the JS gets run. When the JS gets run, that will just be a string constant.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're misunderstanding the way JS and PHP works. PHP works server side, and JS, in your case, client side. And so, PHP generate the script/page before it's sent to the browser, so when JS runs it, all the `<?php ?>` are already replaced by static data.

So, to put it shortly and simply, you just can't call a PHP function from JS after your page is loaded, the way you tried to (because the call isn't there anymore - check your source code from your browser).

You need either to :

- use a form with an "action" attribute ; this will send the data to server, and call the php script set in "action", where you can handle the sent data, and then reload the page with the new/updated data,
- use ajax (almost the same thing : this sends data to server and call a php script to handle them, but instead of reloading the page, the output of the PHP script - with the data you need - will be sent back to JS, to a callback function, where you'll be able to use them to modify the page).